# rotating cube - Textures with alpha - different looks

Tags: opengl, visual-c++

Hi i have some question about texturing cube with alpha.
I have textured cube, and added alpha. When i start program everything (1 screen) is working fine, but when i rotate this cube to the other side (2 screen) i see "front" square with his texture, and behind this i can see another texture from "back" square. Why i see different things depending on which wall i look

this is code which draws my cube

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Cube->Draw();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

[image: print screens]

Comment: Did you enable GL_CULL_FACE? If so, that might explain what you are seeing.

Comment: no, i haven't enable this